# Three20 TTTableViewController + NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, three20

I'm just getting started with the three20 library and thought I'd start by trying to convert a `UITableViewController` into a `TTTableViewController`.  I haven't been able to find any sort of tutorial, article, or anything that shows how to hook up a `TTTableViewController` to an `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Can anyone point me to a good writeup or share some sample code that shows how to do this?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill,

I had problems with this as well when I first looked at Three20.  The best documentation for Three20 isn't on the Web -- it's in the sample code inside the Three20 repository.  You'll see a directory called "Samples" or something to that effect that has some useful examples on how to actually use things, and it's pretty well commented.